# combine search from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

The current table structure we have is

```
product_description [
    (INT)product_id, 
    (VARCHAR)name, 
    (TEXT)description, ...
]
vendors [
    (INT)vendor_id, 
    (VARCHAR)vendor_name, 
    (TEXT)vendor_description, ...
]
vendor [
    (INT)vendor, 
    (INT)product_id, ...
]
```

Currently we have a search option where we fetch matching values from both tables. They work independently, i.e. keyword search with LIKE gets matching value from both tables' name as well as description fields.

Now the requirement has been changed by client. Now the client wants the search to be dependent, i.e. suppose some one search for product then their associated vendors should be fetched and if vendor is searched then associated products should be visible. But the issue is there is no option to determine whether user is searching for product or vendor.

Is there any way to make the search dependent?

After search there is also other filter to work out like location, price range, etc. Also the result is displayed on a tab based page where separate tab for vendor and product and each tab has their own pagination which do not affect the other tab.

We suggested to the client to give a drop down like elance does near their search bar so that user can specify what they want to search for, but changing design is not possible now. How to proceed with the searching?

Comment: This kind of functionality will mess the logic and may be in case not produce the desired result to the user. Its good to provide another option to select in products or vendors.

Comment: well thats true. but the client doesn't want to modify the design anymore, and i'm unable to find any logic to implement the searching.

Comment: Best and easiest way is to use two different query one for product and one for vendors as you are displaying tabs based result and both have pagination. So this is good solution for such requirement.

Comment: Please ask client "is it possible to say for which one i should give more priority?" ie... if more priority is for "product" then that table will search first, if that entry present in product table it will display details. If that entry not present in product table it will search in vendor table. is it ok?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP that seems to be a logical way. I'll ask and update. thanks.

Comment: @FathahRehmanP as said by client, "This approach is not acceptable." :`(  In case priority is given, it becomes difficult to give proper ranking to vendors on search result. Any other ideas??

Comment: @Sp0T - Assume user searched a value that exists in both product table and vendor table, then what should be the result??

Answer (score 0):

After some convincing we were able to modify the client's requirement to solve both implementation problem as well as provide appropriate value upon search. As per the new search guidelines provided, the conditions are:

1. If  < Keyword > == PRODUCT , then show PRODUCT on PRODUCT tab, and related vendors selling those PRODUCTS along with < Keyword > match of VENDORS.
2. If  < Keyword > == VENDOR , then show VENDOR on VENDOR tab, and only < Keyword > match of PRODUCTS.

So basically, vendors are dependent while, products will be independent.

QUERY USED for Product -

```
SELECT 
    p.product_id, 
    pd.product_type, 
    (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) 
        AS 
        rating, 
    (SELECT price FROM product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) 
        AS 
        discount,
    (SELECT price FROM product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) 
        AS 
        special 
FROM product p 
LEFT JOIN product_description pd 
    ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN product_to_store p2s 
    ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE pd.language_id = '1' 
    AND p.status = '1' 
    AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
    AND p2s.store_id = '0' 
    AND ( pd.name LIKE '%<KEYWORD>%' 
        OR 
        pd.description LIKE '%<KEYWORD>%' 
        OR 
        pd.tag LIKE '%<KEYWORD>%' 
        OR 
        LCASE(p.model) = '<KEYWORD>' 
        ) 
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY p.image DESC, LCASE(pd.name) 
ASC 
LIMIT 0,15
```

QUERY USED for Vendor-

```
SELECT 
     DISTINCT (vds.vendor_id), 
     vds . * 
 FROM vendors vds
 LEFT JOIN user u 
      ON ( vds.user_id = u.user_id ) 
 LEFT JOIN vendor v
      ON vds.vendor_id = v.vendor
 LEFT JOIN product_description pd
      ON v.vproduct_id = pd.product_id
 LEFT JOIN product p 
      ON v.vproduct_id = p.product_id
 WHERE u.status = '1'
      AND p.status = '1'
      AND vds.display_vendor = '1'
      AND (
            LOWER( vds.vendor_name ) LIKE LOWER( "%<KEYWORD>%" ) 
            OR 
            LOWER( vds.vendor_description ) LIKE LOWER( "%<KEYWORD>%" ) 
            OR 
            LOWER( pd.name ) LIKE LOWER( "%<KEYWORD>%" ) 
            OR
            LOWER( pd.description ) LIKE LOWER( "%<KEYWORD>%" ) 
       )
 ORDER BY vds.vendor_name 
 ASC 
 LIMIT 0 , 30
```